# What is this icon on top of all my games?

Tags: windows

I'm seeing the icon below (bottom right) in all my games. At first I thought it was something from UPlay, but it's also shown in other games. Does anybody recognize it and know how to get rid of it? Clicking it (when the game controls allow it) doesn't do anything.

This is on a Windows PC.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

After some digging I found that it's from [Nvidia Shadowplay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Shadowplay), which I'd inadvertently enabled recently.

Comment: You can change that icon's position or turn it off entirely in GFE (GeForce Experience) under `Preferences > ShadowPlay`. Make sure you select `Status Indicator` unter `Overlays` first, though.